# wxPython - frame showing up mostly offscreen, self.Center() not working - related to system display settings?

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython

*Note: I've determined that this issue has to do with my display settings. When I run my code on my laptop (win. 10 display settings: res. = 1920x1080, scale = 150%), the issue occurs. When I'm at work, with the laptop connected to a larger external monitor (w10 display settings: res. 1920x1080, scale=100%), everything is fine and dandy. Is there a way to create this frame such that it'll show up correctly regardless of the user's display settings? I suspect many of my users will run into this issue -- we all use the same model laptop and similar external displays, and the display settings I mentioned above are the W10 default (/'Recommended') display settings for the respective displays.

I've got a program that runs fine until the very last frame. In previous versions, the last frame showed up fine. Then when I added a plot canvas to the frame, needing it now to be wider, I was having a hell of a time getting the frame to resize itself to accommodate the plot -- `Layout()` didn't work, `SetSizerAndFit(sizer)` didn't work.. So I just hard-coded the size.

Now my issue is that when the frame is displayed (just `resframe = ResultsFrame(None); resframe.Show()`, it appears with most of the upper-left half waay off screen (see image below). Here's the code for a mockup of the issue. Actually this one shows up huge - still positioned outside the screen boundary but now also extending past the screen in all directions. The inspection tool still shows it's only 1290x945 (I'm using a laptop with a 1920x1080 screen) but that's obviously not right. Regardless, the frame is still positioned in the same location (offscreen) as the real one from my program.

What am I doing wrong?

Copy/pasting important bit I left out in response to comments: Forgot to mention the behavior is the same when using `pos = wx.DefaultPosition` as well as just leaving pos out of the `__init__`; I also can't drag the window around since the entire top bar is offscreen. The main issue isn't size, it's position. The dummy script I wrote (for whatever reason) appears huge onscreen (despite showing the correct size in the inspection tool), but in the actual app I am writing, the frame is the right size, just positioned offscreen. The size issue seen in the dummy script is weird (sizes in InspectionTool all return 1920x945 yet the frame appears far bigger than the screen size, despite being 1920x1080), but does not occur in my actual program, so I'm more concerned with the positioning.

```
import wx

class ResultFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(ResultFrame, self).__init__(parent, -1, title = "Results",
         size = wx.Size(1290,945), pos = wx.Point(50,50), style = wx.CAPTION|
         wx.CLOSE_BOX|wx.MINIMIZE_BOX|wx.SYSTEM_MENU)

        self.InitUI()
        self.Layout()
        self.Center()

    def InitUI(self):
        self.mainpnl = wx.Panel(self)
        self.nbpnl = wx.Panel(self.mainpnl)
        self.ctrlpnl = wx.Panel(self.mainpnl)
        self.mainsizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.ctrlsizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        self.restart = wx.Button(self.ctrlpnl, wx.ID_ANY, "Start Over",\
         size=(100,40))
        self.interp = wx.Button(self.ctrlpnl, wx.ID_ANY, "Help Interpreting\n"
         "Results", size=(100,40))
        self.nb = wx.Notebook(self.mainpnl)
        for tar in range(0,4):
            self.nb.AddPage(wx.Panel(self.nb), f"page {tar}")
        self.ctrlsizer.Add(self.restart, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        self.ctrlsizer.AddStretchSpacer()
        self.ctrlsizer.Add(self.interp, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        self.ctrlpnl.SetSizerAndFit(self.ctrlsizer)
        self.mainsizer.Add(self.ctrlpnl, 0, wx.ALL, 0)
        self.mainsizer.Add(self.nb, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.mainpnl.SetSizerAndFit(self.mainsizer)

        self.CreateStatusBar()
        self.SetStatusText("Results")

def main():
    import wx.lib.mixins.inspection
    app = wx.App()
    frm = ResultFrame(None)
    frm.Show()
    wx.lib.inspection.InspectionTool().Show(refreshTree=True)
    app.MainLoop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

[image: Frame appearing offscreen, with inspector for details]

Comment: You are giving it a fixed starting position `pos = wx.Point(50,50)` so don't `Center` it. If it's too big for the screen, you'll have to drag it around.

Comment: Forgot to mention the behavior is the same when using `pos = wx.DefaultPosition` as well as just leaving `pos` out of the `__init__`; I also can't drag the window around since the entire top bar is offscreen. The main issue isn't size, it's position. The dummy script I wrote (for whatever reason) appears huge onscreen (despite showing the correct size in the inspection tool), but in the actual app I am writing, the frame is the right size, just positioned offscreen. Will update question to include this.